# HTML: td layout issue

Tags: html

Really couldn't draw something good here, so drew it in Excel.

[image]

Here is I tried to render some code in HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>
        <th>
        <th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

        <p></p>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
<table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `colspan` to merge across columns like so:

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="3">This is how I want it to look</td>
</tr>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/82Lz3spf/)

Answer (score 3):

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">7</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>TH</th>
    <th>TH</th>
    <th>TH</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TD</td>
    <td>TD</td>
    <td>TD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=3>TD</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TD</td>
    <td>TD</td>
    <td>TD</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```